# CMake with Maven and JNI

Tags: java, maven, cmake, java-native-interface

I'm using CMake to call Maven, which generates a JAR file that I want later to create JNI headers for.

```
...
find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI  REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

set(PROJECT_TARGET_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/target")
set(PROJECT_JAR "core-${VERSION}.jar")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/${PROJECT_JAR}"
    COMMAND mvn clean install
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
add_custom_target(
    JavaProject ALL
    DEPENDS "${PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/${PROJECT_JAR}"
)
create_javah(
    TARGET JavaHeaders
    CLASSES com.some.class
    CLASSPATH "${PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/${PROJECT_JAR}"
    DEPENDS JavaProject
    OUTPUT_NAME MyHeaders.h
)
```

The problem with this approach is though that the JAR is only generated at **build time**, but `create_javah` checks its presence at the `CLASSPATH` at **buildsystem generation time**, even though I specified that it depends on the target `JavaProject`:

```
...
-- Found Java: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java (found version "1.8.0.151") 
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so  
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/UseJava.cmake:1293 (message):
  create_javah: CLASSPATH entry
  /path/to/target/core-5.12.0.3.jar does
  not exist.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  jni/NsEttPos/CMakeLists.txt:17 (create_javah)
```

How can I skip this check at the generation time?

Comment: Have you considered using [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to build everything?

Comment: The reason I'm using CMake is that we have a whole bunch of C++ files to work with.

Comment: yep, and gradle can build everything... C++, java, and any other language you happen to build

Comment: [building native software](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html), [java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create_javah` `CLASSPATH` option can specify directories, already existing jar files or targets created with [add_jar](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html?highlight=add_jar) command. Only if the jar file is created by a CMake `add_jar` command, it is allowed to exist only at build time.

However since the `create_javah` only checks for the presence of a `JAR_FILE` property, you can try to apply the following hack:

```
add_custom_target(
    JavaProject ALL
    DEPENDS "${PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/${PROJECT_JAR}"
)
# Add a JAR_FILE property to the JavaProject for create_javah
set_property(
    TARGET JavaProject 
    PROPERTY JAR_FILE "${PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/${PROJECT_JAR}"
)
```

Then pass the `JavaProject` target directly to the `create_javah` `CLASSPATH` option:

```
create_javah(
    TARGET JavaHeaders
    CLASSES com.some.class
    CLASSPATH JavaProject
    OUTPUT_NAME MyHeaders.h
)
```

Also note that `DEPENDS JavaProject` is no longer necessary, because `create_javah` automatically adds a dependency to it.

Comment: Funny enough, I've eventually arrived at the same hacky solution myself: `set_target_properties(JavaProject PROPERTIES JAR_FILE "${PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/${JAR_FILE}")`